# Excel: Extracting the row name and column name corresponding to the MAX value in my DataTable

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

[image: ExcelSheet]

In cell **K1=MAX(J7:AM36)**
I have the maximum value of the data table, I want to extract the corresponding StopLoss% ( This is my column headers, they are %) to Cell K2 and also my TakeProfit% ( This is my row headers they are also %) to K3

I am not sure how to go about this, Index with Match functions won't work because I want to search across the whole data table.

There is also the problem with duplicates that I am not sure how to deal with. Prefered if the lowest StopLoss% and lowest TakeProfit% is prioritized, then it would also work fine if there are duplicates.

This can be done in VBA or normal formulae, I am just not proficient enough yet!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Formula

- Finds the lowest independent value for each of **StopLoss** and **TakeProfit**
- Allows for different **StopLoss**/**TakeProfit** headings values in the future.
  Example: `{0.5%; 1%; 1.5%; ...}` instead of `{1%; 2%; 3%;. ..}`

##### Named Ranges

| Name | Range | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **`maxRet`** | `K1` | **Max Return** (lookup value) |
| **`stopHead`** | `J6:AM6` | **stopLoss** headings row (values) |
| **`takeHead`** | `I7:I36` | **takeProfit** headings column (values) |

##### StopLoss Formula

- [BYROW](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) maps each row of `data` into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67)
- [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) assigns an arbitrarily chosen name `r` to represent each mapped row in the formula
- [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) returns the position of `maxRet` in each row, and [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) returns a blank value `""` if the lookup value is not found
- [MIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152) returns the lowest number from the array of positions found
- [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) finds the `stopHead` value in the same column position as the [MIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152) value

```
=INDEX(stopHead,, MIN(
     BYROW(data,  LAMBDA(r,
        IFERROR(MATCH(maxRet, r, 0),"")
     ))
))
```

##### takeProfit Formula

- [BYCOL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/bycol-function-58463999-7de5-49ce-8f38-b7f7a2192bfb) maps each column of `data` into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67)
- [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) assigns an arbitrarily chosen name `c` to represent each mapped column in the formula
- [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) returns the position of `maxRet` in each column, and [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) returns a blank value `""` if the lookup value is not found
- [MIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152) returns the lowest number from the array of positions found
- [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) finds the `takeHead` value in the same row position as the [MIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/min-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152) value

```
=INDEX(takeHead, MIN(
     BYCOL(data, LAMBDA(c,
        IFERROR(MATCH(maxRet, c, 0), "")
     ))
 ),1)
```

[image]